# Resolução de Exercicio

Tags: portugol-studio

Estou fazendo um exercício de algoritmo no PortugolStudio. Mas solucionei partes do exercício.Depois de 2 dias de tentativa não consegui solucionar uma questão.Quem puder me ajudar agradeceria muito.

programa
{

```
funcao inicio()
{
    inteiro anos,qnt_cigarro,dias,min,totalCig,dias_perdidos

    escreva("{Exercício 10 - Não Fume}\n\n")
    escreva("Cada cigarro reduz 10 minutos de vida \n")
    escreva("--------------------------------------\n")
    escreva("Há quantos anos você fuma? ")
    leia(anos)
    escreva("Quantos cigarros você fuma por dia? ")
    leia(qnt_cigarro)
    escreva("--------------------------------------\n\n")

    //Conversões 
    dias = anos * 365 //Anos para dia
    min = dias * 1440 //Dias para minutos Obs: 1440 é minutos equivale a um dia

    //Total de cigarros e dias de vida a menos
    totalCig = qnt_cigarro * dias
    dias_perdidos = totalCig * 10 /1440 //(totalCig * 10) -> em minutos / 1440 ->trasformado em dia



    escreva(dias+" dias equivale "+min+" a minutos. \n")
    escreva("Ao todo, até agora você já fumou "+totalCig+" cigarros!\n")
    escreva("Estima-se que você já perdeu "+dias_perdidos+" dias de vida.!\n")


    /* Entrada de dados:
     * 8 anos  2920 dias
     * 5 dias*/  

     /* Resultados
     * 8 anos -> 2920 dias  -> 4204800 min
     * 14600 cigarros fumados
     * 101.39 dias de vida 
     */

     //Resolvido por Luiz Augusto StackOverflow
}
```

}

Comment: pq dividido por 105?

Comment: Nessa tentativa.Seria dividido por 10.Porque cada cigarro representa 10min a menos de vida. .Acabei inserindo errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a cada cigarro fumado você perderá 10 minutos de vida, multiplique a variável `totalCig` por 10, entretanto, neste momento, você terá os valores em minuto.

Então para transformar os valores de minuto para dia: divida por 1440.

Seu código ficará assim:

```
    dias = anos * 365
    totalCig = qnt_cigarro * dias
    dia_para_min = dias * 1440 //1440 é minutos em um dia
    dias_vida = (totalCig * 10) / 1440 // Aqui está a solução
    ...
    escreva("Estima-se que você já perdeu "+dias_vida+" dias de vida.!")
```